# Setting ActionMode Background programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am aware of `android:actionModeBackground` that can be used in XML themes.

Is there a way to set this background in code?

Basically I need the ActionMode equavalent of

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: Using reflection would probably work, but it means getting your hands dirty with stuff you're not really supposed to touch. Also, there are no guarantees about forward and/or backward compatibility for such a solution. Anyways, just a thought.

Comment: You can find the answer in this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556116/how-can-i-customize-the-action-modes-color-and-text

Comment: You'll have to use reflection. [How to animate background of ActionMode of the ActionBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457709/how-to-animate-background-of-actionmode-of-the-actionbar)

Comment: Strange how my 11 month old question can be a "asked before and already has an answer" yet the question I am supposedly duplicating is only days old.

Comment: check this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23457709/how-to-animate-background-of-actionmode-of-the-actionbar) answer

Comment: Then how it is implemented in Gmail app? Default - red, selection mode - gray, search mode - white. I don't believe Google used reflection for this in their app.

Comment: Since asking the question, I solved my issue by making my own actionmode with a toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin using Android Studio 3.4.2:

```
(actionMode as? StandaloneActionMode).let {
    val contextView = it?.javaClass?.getDeclaredField("mContextView")
    contextView?.isAccessible = true

    val standActionMode = contextView?.get(it)
    val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorResId)
    (standActionMode as? View)?.setBackgroundColor(color)
}
```

To cast `actionMode` to `StandaloneActionMode`, don't forget to import `ActionMode` from `androidx.appcompat.view.ActionMode` and not from `android.view.ActionMode`.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out with reflection help. Because I dont have an actionbar

```
public static void setActionModeBackgroundColor(ActionMode actionMode, int color) {
        try {
            StandaloneActionMode standaloneActionMode = (StandaloneActionMode) actionMode;
            Field mContextView = StandaloneActionMode.class.getDeclaredField("mContextView");
            mContextView.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = mContextView.get(standaloneActionMode);
            ((View) value).setBackground(new ColorDrawable(color));
        } catch (Throwable ignore) {
        }
    }
```

Also there are 2 implementations of ActionMode : StandaloneActionMode  and ActionModeImpl. this example only for First one. For second one it will be same

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ActionMode id by using this action_context_bar

```
   int amId = getResources().getIdentifier("action_context_bar", "id", "android");
   View view= findViewById(amId);
   view.setBackground(actionModeBackground);
```