# How to change the Contextual Action Bar color programmatically?

Tags: android, android-styles, programmatically-created, contextual-action-bar, android-actionmode

How can I change my Contextual Action Bar color **programmatically**? That is, not an `xml` solution. For Android.

*Note:*

- I am working with `minsdkVersion 21`
- I am using BigNerdRanch's *MultiSelector*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting ActionMode Background programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089189/setting-actionmode-background-programmatically)