# Showing the menu item in left side of actionbarsherlock

Tags: android

I am trying to make an action bar using actionbarsherlock, which must look like:

[image]

My menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_done"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_done"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Done"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_delete"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_grey"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Share"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_grey"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

How to move the action_done(with tick) menu to left?

Comment: I really dont think there is a way other than using custom View, But wish you good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a 'Contextual ActionBar ActionMode'.

I'm on my phone at the moment but this question seems to point you in the right direction: [How can you implement multi-selection and Contextual ActionMode in ActionBarSherlock?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737519/how-can-you-implement-multi-selection-and-contextual-actionmode-in-actionbarsher)

Comment: Yes,  I used ActionMode now. But I have a problem in it. I am unable to change the color of title.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556116/how-can-i-customize-the-action-modes-color-and-text

It looks like you need to just modify the theme's style to change the colour of the text and background.

Comment: How to set this style on my apptheme? My style.xml: pastie.org/9261136  I also commented there :D

Comment: Sorry, Pastie is blocked for me but if you ask another question on SO and link to it, I'll take a look when I can.

Comment: I already posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064002/change-the-color-of-actionmode-android