# Change the color of title of ActionMode android

Tags: android

This is my action mode bar:

[image]

You can see the light text "1 selected". I am trying from hours to change its color but can't found any solution. Also I want to change the color of the separator in the right side of tick image. Any ideas?

My style.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionStyle</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyTabTextStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/bg_bar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_done</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar_color</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTabTextStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556116/how-can-i-customize-the-action-modes-color-and-text

Comment: @Raghunandan I commented there : "How to use this style in my AppTheme".

Comment: @Raghunandan Can you please tell me how to include the style in my AppTheme style?

Comment: How did you end up going with this?

Comment: @DylanWatson Sorry, its not working. I used black color, but its showing same color as in screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

Using Actionbar Sherlock and XML, you can use `Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode`:

```
<!-- Tell Sherlock to use the customised ActionMode Style --->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyActionModeStyle</item>
</style>

<!-- Setup the style of the ActionMode here --->
<style name="MyActionModeStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/action_bar_color</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/My.ActionMode.Title</item>
</style>

<!-- Setup the text style of the ActionMode here --->
<style name="My.ActionMode.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I want to change the color of title.

Comment: No worries. I've updated to include changing the ActionMode Text colour and style.

Comment: I was finally able to test this myself. I have updated the example with what worked for me.
I was not using ActionBarSherlock, so I had to set my api level to above 14 to use `android:actionModeStyle` but this worked for me. You may also find that `MyActionModeStyle` does not need to inherit from `Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode`, if this also causes issues.

Comment: Ok I will check it :)

Comment: How'd you go, did it work?