# Android 5 change status bar color under ActionMode

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

Hi I want to change status bar color in ActionMode like Inbox app and Gmail app do. I know I can use `setStatusBarColor`, but is there any other way to do this? Like define status bar color of ActionMode in styles.xml?

Comment: Have you tried [adding a style](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8640186/1133344) and then [setting it on your theme](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21853074/1133344)?

Comment: @AlexandruRosianu I want to know if there is an attribute of style corresponds to this color.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question. I don't think you can do this using only styles.

Answer (score 1):

I can give you an idea on how you can get it done.

1) Firstly, just check when the ActionMode is turned on. I am sure you can do that so I am not elaborating on that.

2) Now, just set the color using the setStatusBarColor method of the Windows class. You ca check this answer to have a detailed insight on the problem and the solution.

Hope it helps. Do let me know if I can help you any further.