# ActionMode Title Font

Tags: android, titlebar, custom-font, android-actionmode

I recently created an application that uses a custom font pack in the whole app. But when I use the ActionMode, the title does not use the custom font. So does anyone know how I can apply a custom font to the title of the ActionMode?

The font of the Action Mode title does not match the other TextViews in the app.

See the picture below

https://photos.app.goo.gl/cP1uuHkzHkWshabY7

Answer (score 0):

You can change actionMode title font using custom `actionMode` `style`

***first create custom style***

```
<style name="ActionMode" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/ActionMode.Title</item>
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/ActionMode.Title</item>
</style>
<style name="ActionMode.Title" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionMode.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">your color</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/yourfont</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/your font</item>
    <item name="textSize">15sp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15sp</item>
</style>
```

***Now put in to your main style `style.xml`***

```
<style name="Theme.Tarif.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode" tools:targetApi="p">shortEdges</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/light_primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/light_primary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/green_500</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/light_primary</item>

    <!--ActionMode-->
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/ActionMode</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

I will search for 'Theme' related properties to change the actionbar font as I believe it is linked to that. Here is a link to a similar problem: [How can I customize the Action Mode's color and text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6556116/10197813)

It uses 'Size' attribute to do the job.

```
<style name="Widget.ActionMode">
<item name="android:background">?android:attr/actionModeBackground</item>
<item name="android:backgroundSplit">?android:attr/actionModeSplitBackground</item>
<item name="android:height">?android:attr/actionBarSize</item>
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Title</item>
<item name="android:subtitleTextStyle">@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That's not really an answer, you should either make it a comment or do the search yourself and show what you found.

Comment: I wanted to make it a comment but the system did't let me. I wanted to point in the right direction

Comment: It change the color and size of text but not the font : /